# buttons styling in confirm Modal

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I have project and this project contains many of interfaces, and among these interfaces, there are interface to upload image, and i have delete button on this image to confirm delete image operation,

[image]

and as u can see on the image, there are two buttons, i don't know how can put style to these buttons, i need to put marginRight to "buttons"

how can i solve the problem?

```
const onGalleryFileRemove = (_file: UploadFile<any>) => {
        const { confirm } = Modal

        return new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {
            confirm({
                title: <h3 style={{ marginLeft: '3rem' }}>{formatMessage({ id: 'confirmationDeletePicture' })}</h3>,
                icon: <ExclamationCircleOutlined style={{ float: 'right' }} />,
                onOk: () => {
                    resolve(true)
                },
                onCancel: () => {
                    reject(true)
                }
            })
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass style in `okButtonProps` and `cancelButtonProps` props.

```
Modal.confirm({
    content: 'Hello World',
    cancelButtonProps: {
        style: {
            marginRight: '10px'
        }
    },
    okButtonProps: {
        style: {
            marginRight: '10px'
        }
    }
});
```